# How to stop players from going into the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making an adventure map and players should not be allowed in the Nether.

There's a few things you have to understand:

- Players have access to Flint and Steel.
- Players can make a Nether portal by using a water and a lava bucket.
- Players can go as far as they want, the map is endless so command blocks won't be effective when players walk too far.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code in your [server.properties file](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties):

```
allow-nether=false
```

Comment: I don't think that works in singleplayer.

Comment: This won't work, since the OP does not control the server where the map will be used (assuming that they wishes to distribute).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty easy even if you don't want just to fill the while nether with air.
Use **"Client consent to play fair"**. Basically it's that you prohibit going to the nether in the map rules and players must respect it.

Or use command blocks:

You will have to place and power this **repeat** command block right under the spawn to be always active. Put this inside:

```
 /execute @a ~ ~ ~ fill ~+1 ~+1 ~+1 ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 minecraft:air 0 replace minecraft:nether_portal
```

You can fiddle with the numbers a bit for the best result. If your world gets laggy, you can use a clock and a normal command block instead, or adding a command block with testforblock.

(thanks to skylinerw for the help)